# @expo/vector-icons Ionicons name prop TypeScript error

Tags: typescript, expo, react-native-vector-icons

Using @expo/vector-icons 13.0.0 Ionicons variant, I need to dynamically set the icon name, but the name prop throws a TS error:

> TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"navigate" | "search"
> | "repeat" | "link" | "at" | "notifications" | "body" | "code" | "map"
> | "menu" | "time" | "ellipse" | "filter" | "image" | "stop" | "text" |
> "alert" | "checkbox" | ... 3663 more ... | undefined'.

```
<Ionicons
  name={activeButton === buttonName ? icon.replace('-outline', '') : icon}
  color={
    activeButton !== buttonName
      ? Constants?.manifest?.extra?.tabBarButtonColor
      : Constants?.manifest?.extra?.tabBarButtonActiveColor
  }
  size={24}
/>
```

How can I set `name={activeButton === buttonName ? icon.replace('-outline', '') : icon}` to  TS name type?

Thanks!

Edit 1: Changed a little the code to clarify issue

```
const iconName: ComponentProps<typeof Ionicons>['name'] =
  activeButton === buttonName ? icon.replace('-outline', '') : icon; // <-- this gives the same error

<Ionicons
  name={iconName}
  color={
    activeButton !== buttonName
      ? Constants?.manifest?.extra?.tabBarButtonColor
      : Constants?.manifest?.extra?.tabBarButtonActiveColor
  }
  size={24}
/>
```

Comment: not sure if it's a solution for you, but you can simply add //@ts-ignore above the name and see if it works

Comment: Hi! that's quite right, but I'm looking to a compliant solution for TS

Answer (score 3):

Give your icon variable type as this:

```
const icon: React.ComponentProps<typeof MaterialCommunityIcons>['name'] = 'add-outline'
```

Comment: Thanks @Elliot. Your solution didn't solved the issue, please check Edit 1 in original question

Comment: The issue seems to be my manipulation of the icon name text with the replace statement. Is there a way to tell TS that the result of the replace text is of the type ComponentProps<typeof Ionicons>['name']?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to pass multiple Expo vector icons as props in a custom component using Typescript.

```
import { FontAwesome, MaterialIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';


export enum IconType {
  MatetrialIcon,
  FontAweomseIcon,
  Ionicon,
}


type CustomProps = {
   icon: {
     value: { type: IconType.MatetrialIcon, name: keyof typeof MaterialIcons.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.FontAweomseIcon, name: keyof typeof FontAwesome.glyphMap } |
            { type: IconType.Ionicon, name: keyof typeof Ionicons.glyphMap };
     size: number;
   }
   
}


const CustomComponent = (props: CustomProps) => {
const { icon, ...otherProps } = props;

return 
  (
    <View style={styles.customIconStyle}>
      {icon.value.type === IconType.FontAweomseIcon && (
        <FontAwesome name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.MatetrialIcon && (
        <MaterialIcons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
      {icon.value.type === IconType.Ionicon && (
        <Ionicons name={icon.value.name} size={icon.size} />
      )}
    </View>
  );

}
```